# Installation on OS X Mountain Lion: Will not create bootable usb

Tags: installation, 13.04, macosx

I have followed the procedure described when trying to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu 13.04 on OS X, but I get a message that saying that the disk is not readable on this computer. Am I using the wrong .iso, or is the disk of the wrong format?

Answer (score 0):

OS X does weird stuff. Try again using the dd method and write the image to /dev/disk1 (not a partition). Make sure you get your devices right. Also make sure (via Disk Manager) that the disk (and partitions) are not mounted. Finder trys to auto-mount and borks things.

Also Macs are very cranky about what USB media they will boot from. Make sure your using a USB device that you know the mac can boot in the first place. The resulting USB partition will not be readable inside OS X but refit should be able to see and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The disk isn't readable by OSX, but you can manipulate it using `hdiutil` and `dd` in the instructions.  There's just lots of places to go off the rails.